# Is there any alternative for float left and right in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Older version bootstrap was using `.pull-right` and `.pull-left`.

Is there any alternative for `float:left` and `float:right` in bootstrap 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `.pull-left` & `.pull-right`, check out `utilities.less`, you will find the following:

```
// Floats

.clearfix { // Use this to clear floats
  .clearfix();
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.pull-left` and `.pull-right` still exist:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes